# should I use asyncio.run inside a non-main function in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

### QL;DR

In Python, is it a good practice to use `asyncio.run` inside a non-main function?

### Description of the problem

I have a python code that runs multiple commands using subprocesses.

At the moment I run those subprocesses sequentially and wait until each one of the is finished until I run the next one. I want to start avoiding this using the `async` keyword and the `asyncio` library in general.

Now, in python you cannot use the `await` keyword unless you're in an `async` function. This forces you to propagate the `async` prefix to every function that calls on an async function, up until the main function at the top layer. the only way to avoid it that I know is to use `asyncio.run`. However, in all of the tutorials I saw the only place this function is used is when calling the main function, which doesn't help me avoid this propagation.

I was wondering if there is a real reason not to use `asyncio.run` in non-main function and avoid making all of my functions `async` for no reason.

Would love to know the answer!

Comment: There is nothing special about the name “main” in Python. You can name the function that calls `asyncio.run` anything you want. You don’t even need to call `asyncio.run` inside a function. Whether asyncio is the right choice (as opposed to something like concurrent.futures), though, is a different question.

Comment: I sometimes use `trio.run()` or `asyncio.run()` in class `__init__` in some weird cases, I don't think there's limitation where you should call it!

Comment: You only need to use the async def formulation when the function contains an await, an asyncio for, or an async with.  It's very occasionally worthwhile to make an ordinary function into an async def function so it can be used in places where your API requires a coroutine.  You should not make a function async "for no reason."